# Prevent storing output before computation on button press

Tags: digital-logic, synchronization

For a part of a circuit I am trying to design, I need to make sure the output of the circuit is not stored in a memory cell/RS-latch before it is computed, whenever a button is pressed.

[image: The circuit I'm talking about]

As you can see in the image, the signal on the left (indicating whether any of the buttons are pressed), will turn on before the signal on the right (the computed output) will have the right value, because it has to travel through more gates.

**How can I make sure these signals are somehow synchronised, to prevent storing them before the right one is computed?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In analog circuitry you could build a delay circuit. But in Logisim, I think it's impossible... You could always chain a bunch of NOT or buffer gates together to build a delay, and see if Logisim accepts that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "signal" passes 1 more gates than "pressed", Add two more gates (delay) after the "pressed" signal, feed that to the D-FF clock, along with "signal" on data.

In practice, you need debouncing circuitry.